# Windows 10 Pro Wifi card on laptop Lenovo Z580 loses connection intermittently

Tags: windows-10, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have a Lenovo Z580. I have got its hinges repaired from a local repair guy. It has also fallen once but everything works. The problem I have been facing lately is that my Wireless Card doesn't stay connected for more than a few minutes. Its a built in Wireless card (Intel Centrino Wireless N 2200). I use Windows 10 Pro. It installs the Wifi drivers itself but I have tried the latest drivers available for Windows 8.1 also.

Exact problem description: WiFi card randomly disconnects, disables, sometimes reenables itself but sometimes fails to enable giving a Code 10 in Device Manager. Its very frustrating. Sometimes when the laptop is on a stable surface, the wifi card may work longer.

I have tried every solution available on the Internet. Changed my Wifi from Public to Private, turned off "Allow this computer to turn off the Wifi card to save power", changed power settings of the Wireless Adapter to Maximum Performance. None of these solutions have worked for me.

My hunch is that either the hinge guy hasn't fixed the antenna cables properly or the wireless card is at its end of life.

My question is this: How can I determine this before buying a new Wifi card.

Comment: You claim it fell once, but everything works anyway, and yet, the wireless card doesn't work. As such, not everything works...

Comment: Good catch. Let me clarify. It fell once but since then it was working perfectly. I am experiencing the wifi problem only recently months after that disaster. I should probably remove that from the description. It may mislead the viewers.

Comment: The fall could certainly have caused some damage to the card, which could have gotten worse over time. There's likely another answer though.